# Changing style color via javascript not working

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using this code for mouse hover/unhover. Hover works perfectly, but unhover doesn't.

```
    var oldcolor;
    function changeColors(x) {

       oldcolor=x.style.backgroundColor;
    x.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
    x.style.color='red';

}
    function rollback(y){

        y.style.backgroundColor='oldcolor';
      y.style.color='oldcolor';

    }
```

Comment: oldcolor is a string variable, just remove the quote when you make         `y.style.backgroundColor='oldcolor';`

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console? also can you include the elements related to this question. "event calls"

Answer (score 0):

You are using `'oldcolor'` so that is assigning that string. You want to use the variable instead, like this:

```
var oldcolor;

function changeColors(x) {
    oldcolor=x.style.backgroundColor;
    x.style.backgroundColor='yellow';
    x.style.color='red';
}

function rollback(y){
    y.style.backgroundColor=oldcolor;
    y.style.color=oldcolor;
}
```